# Luigi Visualiser to persist jobs for a day

Tags: python, amazon-data-pipeline, luigi

I have been trying with adding --scheduler-remove-delay parameter to job while invoking a run and also in client.cfg I have added remove-delay property

> [scheduler] 
>   record_task_history = True 
>   remove-delay = 86400.0

but none these seem to work. Any ideas?

There is an already almost similar problem here -

[Persist Completed Pipeline in Luigi Visualiser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32636120/persist-completed-pipeline-in-luigi-visualiser#comment67537050_32636120)

Comment: pls show how you're running your task, the path to your code and the path where the client.cfg is located.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the documentation ("remove-delay" instead of remove_delay") which is being fixed under https://github.com/spotify/luigi/issues/2133

You need to put the following in the configuration file:

```
[scheduler]
record_task_history = True
state_path = /x/s/hadoop/luigi/var/luigi-state.pickle
remove_delay = 86400
```